# React Native navigation 0.58.X on Android

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

I am using Native v0.58.3 and I can't seem to get the navigation working.

I can't seem to figure out why it won't work, and I can't find the error when debugging and looking at the docs. The error I get is:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'rngesturehandlermodule.state')

when running this code:

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 * @lint-ignore-every XPLATJSCOPYRIGHT1
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, Navigator, Button, TouchableOpacity, borderRadius} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import TimeLine from './Screens/TimeLine';
import Home from './Screens/Home';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
  Home: { screen: Home },
  TimeLine: { screen: TimeLine },
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
}

);

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, Navigator, Button, TouchableOpacity, borderRadius} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppNavigator, StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1},
  Button: {
  backgroundColor: '#992632',
  marginTop: hp('6.665%'),
  marginBottom: hp('6,665%'),
  marginRight: wp('4%'),
  marginLeft: wp('4%'),
  height: hp('20%'),
  borderRadius: 150,
  }
});

export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
            backgroundColor: '#0a6ca3',
            height: hp('100%'),
          }}>

      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('TimeLine')}
 
          style={styles.Button}>
              <Text style = {{fontSize: 75, color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: hp('4.5%')}}> Tidslinje </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={function(){
            console.log('Rasmus')
          }}
          style={styles.Button}>
            <Text style = {{fontSize: 75, color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: hp('4.5%')}}> Diskussion </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={function(){
            console.log('Rasmus')
          }}
 
          style={styles.Button}> 
          <Text style = {{fontSize: 75, color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: hp('4.5%')}}> Demokrati </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: That error is usually caused by a linking issue. Have you linked the code properly? Also you should wrap your `RootStack` in `createAppNavigator` something like `const AppNav = createAppNavigator(RootStack);` and use `AppNav` in place of `RootStack` In your render

Comment: After adding this code: const AppNav = createAppNavigator(RootStack); to my project it still gives me the same result?

Comment: I know that won’t fix your issue. I was correcting your setup of react-navigation. The error is caused by not linking the package correctly. You need to re-check how you have set it up.

Comment: Also you should state in your question if this is happening on Android, iOS, or both. As that will help narrow down where the problem lies

Comment: Thank you that has been corrected, and i cant find a linking mistake?

Comment: is It happening in Android, iOS, or both?

Comment: Im only trying on android since the project has to turn out on apk, so only android as far as i know

Comment: Did you add the code to the MainActivity?

Comment: I dont have a MainActivity?

Comment: Did you create your project with `expo init` or `react-native init`

Comment: Not sure but im guessing on react-native init, since i dont need the Expo App?

Comment: Look in the root directory of your project, do you see a folder named Android? There should also be one named iOS

Comment: Yes, i see it, im sorry but is there someway to chat with you, i feel like that would speed things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above it is clear that you haven’t performed the final stage of the setup for Android.

In the root directory of your project there is a folder called `android`. You need to look through that folder for a file called `MainActivity.java` It will probably be in `android/app/src/main/java/com/your_app_name/`

Inside that file you need to make some alterations. All the lines that have a plus sign beside them need to be added to the file (obviously you do **not** include the `+`)

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
+ import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Example";
  }

+  @Override
+  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
+    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
+      @Override
+      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
+       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
+      }
+    };
+  }
}
```

You should look at the official documentation for setting up `react-native-gesture-handler` https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

`react-navigation` also explain the steps in detail https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Comment: The:
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
Seems to return an error when i run it?

Comment: You’re probably going to need to open the project in Android Studio and let gradle do its thing. You should also clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a link issue. Did you check out this [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/205) post?

Otherwise you could run

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

and re-install the app (i.e. `yarn run-ios`).

Comment: Im using npm and not yarn, but when i run 'npm link react-native-gesture-handler' i get this error:
npm WARN react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.15 requires a peer of react@> 15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.15 requires a peer of react-native@>= 0.50.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Try running npm install, and verify that react-native is installed. That error is telling us that neither react nor react-native is installed.